# php output buffer not working after php 7.4 to php 8.1 upgrade

Tags: wordpress, output-buffering, php-8.1

The below code is not printing anything in the browser. actually, It should show the header menu.
if I remove ob_start(); and
ob_end_clean() at least its printing menu without CSS.

```php
// Turn on output buffering HTML

ob_start();

echo preg_replace( '/\n|\t/i', '', implode( '' , $wr_nitro_header_html ) );

WR_Nitro_Header_Builder::prop( 'html', ob_get_contents() );

ob_end_clean()
```

update:  same code is working fine for php7.4
but php8.1 is not working

Comment: WR Nitro is a proprietary theme. You might be able to get some help from their support staff.

Comment: How are you switching between 7.4 and 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

Your theme may not be compatible with 8.1, as there are several breaking changes introduced when migrating from 7.4 to 8.1. Try adding:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

to your wp-config.php file and see if errors print to the DOM, or make the display false and check debug.log if you are concerned about printing errors.

Then, reach out to the theme company directly and asking if they are compatible with PHP 8.1.

Answer (score -1):

There is a compatibility issue because the [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) has been changed in PHP 8.1

In PHP 8.1. you have to use the new aliases instead of using the PHP 7.4 `ob_*` functions.

For example:

```php
use function OutputControl\ob_start;
use function OutputControl\ob_end_flush;
use function OutputControl\ob_get_clean;

ob_start();

echo "Hello, world!";

ob_end_flush();

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Alternatively, you can use the `OutputControl` namespace like that:

```php
use OutputControl;

// Enable output buffering
ob_start();

echo "Hello, world!";

ob_end_flush();

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using this code since a while [link](https://pastebin.com/aFBPSt6P), but I'm failing to address Twitter/Reddit embed strings or the iFrame code they're creating (GTag works). In addition I'm getting this error:

`PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush(): Failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush in [...]child/functions.php` (using WP 6.0.3, PHP 8.1.13)

I'm getting PHP deprecated errors too, but as long as everything is working it's not too bad, right?

Could you, by any chance, help me to tweak the code of your example to my use case?